# Does setting a user password on Windows XP help protect against remote exploits compared to no password?

Tags: passwords, windows, remote-desktop

In a typical home user situation with a PC connected to the internet via a router, suppose we are not concerned with protecting the machine from people with physical access. Does setting a password on a Windows XP user account help secure the machine from remote exploits? (compared to a passwordless account).

With no password set at all, remote desktop access is (should) not be possible. Are there other attack vectors where having a password reduces risk? In short, what is more secure?

Comment: Within your question you are talking of 2 different sorts of attacks: remote exploit and remote desktop access. Which one do you really want to protect your computer from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no additional protection against remote exploits, but **you should always set an account password wherever humanly possible**, for a whole host of reasons not related to remote code execution bugs.

Remote exploits usually result in code execution, and that code would run under the privilege level of the user that was running the exploited service or application. As such, the password mechanism is *entirely* bypassed.

This is especially the case for services running under dedicated service accounts, such as NETWORK SERVICE, LOCAL SERVICE, or SYSTEM, which don't *technically* have passwords in the first place - they have NTLM hashes with random values, and login is disabled for them.

The only protection I can see is in a scenario where a low-privilege user (e.g. a limited or guest account) runs an application that is open to the network, and that application is exploited. From there, a passwordless account is a target for horizontal privilege escalation, or vertical privilege escalation if the account runs as administrator.

All in all, I would suggest that a password is **always** set on all user accounts, but not for remote exploitation protection reasons. There are so many other reasons to set a password.

Comment: I think that a password should be set to any account, unless you can prove that any server code is correctly protected against any form of priviledge escalation.

Comment: @danielAzuelos That's exactly what I said in the last paragraph.

Comment: → Polynomial: I read it, and agree. But your answer started with a clear *No*. And I'm afraid this is the part of your answer *fast(small) readers* will retain :(.

Comment: The question was "does setting a user password on Windows XP help protect against remote exploits?", and the answer to that is no. An account password offers no protection **against remote exploits**. An account password offers protection against a range of *other things*. However, I have modified the opening sentence to make this clear from the outset.

Comment: → Polynomial: do you mean that on Windows XP an account **with no password** doesn't permit a **remote exploit**? Is there a security mechanism that would block any remote account access when its password is missing or empty?

Comment: @danielAzuelos Remote exploits don't require you to know the password - that's why they're exploits. If you're referring to gaining access to the system via access to legitimate services, that's a different story, and it's not what OP asked about. If no password is set on an account, you cannot RDP to that account by default. SMB access might be possible, but that would only allow access to resources that were explicitly shared with that user. Either way, it's outside the scope of the question.

Comment: @danielAzuelos You seem to be confusing misconfiguration with remote exploits. Misconfiguration might involve getting access to a service via a weak or missing password on an account, but it doesn't require there to be any bugs in the service software. Remote exploits require a vulnerability to exist in the software, which is completely unrelated to configuration. There's an important distinction between the two.

Comment: → Polynomial: remote exploit may strike directly within a faulty code arriving within a system process. Some other exploits will take advantage of an access with no password and then use a faulty code to gain a system priviledge.
A well known example in security history is the use of guest accounts (on any kind of systems) to lead to a remote exploit of a system.

Comment: @danielAzuelos "A well known example in security history is the use of guest accounts (on any kind of systems) to lead to a remote exploit of a system." - this is a **configuration** issue, not an **exploitation** issue. Having no password on a guest account doesn't make a damn bit of difference to a remote attacker if he can't authenticate remotely as guest. Remote exploits **do not** heed normal authentication policy - they bypass it. Also keep in mind that vertical privilege escalation on Windows has nothing to do with passwords - all Administrator accounts are forced to use passwords.

Comment: @danielAzuelos Guest accounts are used to login, then to kick off local exploits. The fact that the person executing the exploit is not local to the machine does not make the event a remote exploit.

Comment: → schroeder: for security specialists, you're right this kind of remote exploit isn't a direct deep within Windows code or server code attack. But for everybody, this isn't called a "local exploit" either ☺. For my many millions users, an exploit of any form of vulnerability which can be initiated from the outside of the OS is a "remote exploit". I hope I made here my point clearer to avoid any confusion towards the *real victims* of everyday *remote exploits*.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have no external hardware firewall (mostly there is one in the router) and you have file services enabled or things like that, then the remote side could simply connect to your \system\c$ share and place any malware there or whatever. With RPC access the attacker could place things into the registry, etc. If your firewall is blocking that, you're safe against these attacks.

Keep in mind that XP is out of Microsoft support in a few months. That means that if a new remote exploit gets discovered, you won't even get a security bugfix for it.

Comment: *"then the remote side could simply connect to your \system\c$ share and place any malware there or whatever"* - this hasn't been possible for a long time, assuming the systems are patched to SP2 or later.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there other attack vectors where having a password reduces risk?

The fleshy things that poke the keyboard are well known to be exceptionally insecure and often are more exploitable than the operating system itself.

Perhaps you should revisit not being concerned with protecting the machine from them, as well as applying principles of least privilege (to the point of having 2 accounts for yourself so you're not admin when you don't need to be.)